# Netacad.com fail to load timezone and javascript from their server

Tags: javascript, windows

I am a student in netacad.com and I cant find any support department or email to ask them for my problem.

The problem that I faced is for browsers (chrome, firefox, explorer).

I can't see my student materials which is obviously in javascript.

I tryed to enter from other computer and everything is fine. The problem is only in my pc. I use windows 8.1 and this problem appeared today.

Bellow is the console log.

[image]

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

require-749d0c60e9.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: vendor/timezone/el_gr
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

newrelic_prod.js:1 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: timezone_plugin!_unnormalized3,timezone_plugin!
```

I tryed also to clear my sessions and cookies from history browser but nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: If it is not a javascript problem what it is?

Comment: If you were the author of the JavaScript code and needed help with that, it would be a different story. As it stands, though, you are having difficulty **using** a web application written by someone else. This question is offtopic (see [help/dont-ask] and [help/on-topic]).